# &:hover shows Unknown property name and does not work

Tags: css, hover

I'm stuck. Tried to make my css smaller by using &:hover and &:focus properties and it always drops an Unknown property name error and does not work.

The css code is as follows:

```css
/* enter code here */

.pageElement a.main {
  font-size: 0.95vw;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-stretch: semi-condensed;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#46c7e7, #4689E7);
  padding: 6px 14px 8px 14px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
  margin: 0 0 0 4%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#DB0000, #A80000);
  }
}
```

and the result is:

[Unknown property name error by using &:hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtVd0.png)

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Comment: & used in that way is not pure CSS so the error is correct. Did you pick up the idea of using & from say SCSS (a preprocessor)? You have not tagged SCSS so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is nested like SASS - this won't work with pure CSS. So use a preprocessor or write it this way:

```css
.pageElement a.main {
  font-size: 0.95vw;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-stretch: semi-condensed;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#46c7e7, #4689E7);
  padding: 6px 14px 8px 14px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
  margin: 0 0 0 4%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
  
.pageElement a.main:hover,
.pageElement a.main:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#DB0000, #A80000);
}
```